# Aptana 3 Software installer couldn't find URL

Tags: installation, repository, aptana, aptana3

I keep getting this message on the Available Sofwares.

> Could not find  http://downlaod.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update

Can you kindly let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have same errors. Don't know why. :(

Answer (score 0):

To update **Aptana Studio** as an Eclipse plugin you should use:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/stable/

or:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/stable/

for the standalone version.

Change *stable* to *rc* for the beta versions.
You might also need to check wether the plugin is supposed to be compatible with your Eclipse version.

**Appcelerator Studio** downloads are available from:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/appc-studio/

but currently the plugin version is not present anymore.

Additional information is available from the Aptana page on **Eclipse Marketplace**:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aptana-studio-3